# an elementary limit calculation similar to Napier

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

Do someone know how could I calculate the following limit

$$\lim_{x\to0} \frac{e-(1+x)^{1/x}}{x}$$ when x goes to zero. e is Napier.

Comment: cf : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/879085/another-method-for-limit-of-e-1x1-x-x-as-x-approaches-zero

Answer (score 0):

You can compute this as

- the limit of a difference quotient for $f(x)=(1+x)^{1/x}$ or
- via the power series of logarithm and exponential.